# how to combine pygame and tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I have python snake game which is written by pygame and i have a start window(like the ones you see at the start of games) which is written with tkinter.I want to combine them;first the tkinter window come, and the users clicks on play,then the pygame window show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Tk window's `mainloop` function will delay execution of the rest of the script until the window is destroyed. So, for example:

```
import Tkinter as Tk
import pygame

root = Tk.Tk()
root.title('Intro')

playButton = Tk.Button(root, text='Play', command=root.destroy)
playButton.pack()

root.mainloop() # Rest of the script won't execute until playButton pressed

# Initialize pygame window
```